# Syntax for accessing files in a jar and passing them as an argument with Java Web Start

Tags: java, jar, arguments, embedded-resource, java-web-start

I have a program where when I supply a config file at the command line. For ex, `java myProgram myconfig.pb`

My .pb file exist in a jar resource in my .jnlp file. The .pb file exists at the top level of a jar. Should I be able to access it and make it an argument? I am not sure about the syntax for referencing it in my jnlp file.

```
.
<argument>verbose</argument>
<argument>"what do I put in here?"/myconfig.pb</argument>
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is in the root of the Jar, the path to access it would be `/myconfig.pb`.  I.E.

```xml
// ..
<argument>verbose</argument>
<argument>/myconfig.pb</argument>
// ..
```

Just make sure the case is correct.  E.G. A string of  `/myconfig.pb` will *not* locate a file called  `/MyConfig.pb`.